# Scheduling tasks at 1 KHz frequency in Linux

Tags: java, linux, timer, scheduler, milliseconds

For a control system software we are building, there is a requirement to schedule tasks at 1 KHz frequency. This means we need to schedule tasks periodically per millisecond.

We have looked at java.util.Timer and java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

We have also looked at Akka Scheduler.

In all the above mentioned APIs, we see that on scheduling per millisecond, some of the ticks in between get missed.

Is there a way (either with Java/C/C++ or System call) to schedule tasks at 1KHz frequency reliably.

Comment: I am not an expert but I think at this rate, if you need that much precision, you need a real-time grade system, not a general-purpose operating system.

Comment: And if you are using Java, you need RT Java, not standard Java SE / ME / Android

Comment: @StephenC Is there any open source RealTime Java that we can try?

Comment: AFAIK, no there isn't